# What am I doing wrong - syntax error unexpected '\n', expecting =>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my Ruby code (I am following along in Hartl's Ruby on Rails guide) this is the User_test.rb

```
test "email validation should accept valid addresses" do
  valid_addresses = %w[user@example.com USER@foo.com A_US-ER@foo.bar.org
                       first.last@foo.jp alice+bob@baz.cn]
  valid_addresses.each do |valid_address|
    @user.email = valid_address
    assert @user.valid?, "#{valid_address.inspect} should be valid"
  end
end

test "email validation should reject invalid addresses" do
  invalid_addresses = %w[user@example,com user_at_foo.org user.name@example.
                         foo@bar.baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
  invalid_addresses.each do |invalid_address|
    @user.email = invalid_address
    assert_not @user.valid?, "#{invalid_address.inspect} should be invalid"
  end
end
```

The error is as follows and I cannot figure out how to fix it - any more experienced people know what I am doing wrong?

```
 1) Error:
UserTest#test_email_validation_should_reject_invalid_addresses:
SyntaxError: /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/models/user.rb:4: syntax error,       unexpected '\n', expecting =>
```

Here is the User.rb code

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :microposts

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50},
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255},
  format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: true, case_sensitive: false              
end
```

Comment: You've pasted your test code, but it looks like your syntax error is in your user model

Comment: (1) Please pay more attention to how you format your code, your strange indentation (and lack thereof) makes your code very difficult to read. (2) You have a stray trailing comma on the third line of your `User` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50},
```

You need to remove the `,`, Ruby thinks you're continuing the definition of your Hash otherwise.

`unexpected '\n', expecting =>`
basically means that Ruby wasn't expecting a new line, but the definition of an Hash with a key followed by a `=>` and a value.

PS: One more reason I don't really like the abbreviated Ruby Hash notation. There's no `=>` to be found in the code, which makes it harder to understand the error message.